# undefined reference to `ass_renderer_init' ffmpeg

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, codeblocks

Переношу проект с Win7 на Ubuntu (14.04.4).
Возникла проблема с библиотеками ffmpeg.
Установил ffmpeg следующим образом (версия 3.0.0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media && sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8E51A6D660CD88D67D65221D90BD7EACED8E640A
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Среду выбрал Code::Blocks (16.01). В заголовочном файле указал (использовал один файл, чтобы подключить все используемые библиотеки. Этот файл подключаю ко всем остальным через `#pragma once`):

```
extern "C"
{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libavutil/avstring.h>
#include <libavutil/md5.h>
#include <libavutil/mem.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
}
```

В `Build options-> Search directories -> Compiler` указал (туда установился ffmpeg):

> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/include

В `Build options-> Search directories -> Linker` указал:

> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib

В `Build options-> Linker Settings -> Other linker options`:

```
 -lavdevice -lavfilter -lpostproc -lavformat -lavcodec -lrt -ldl -lXfixes -lXext -lX11-lasound -lSDL -lvorbisenc -lvorbis -ltheoraenc -ltheoradec -logg -lz -lrt -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lm -lz -lswresample -lpthread -lfreetype
```

Поробовал добавить в `..->Link Libraries`:

```
../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a
../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavdevice.a
../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a
../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavresample.a
../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavutil.a
../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libpostproc.a
../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libswresample.a
../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libswscale.a
```

Включил поддержку `С++11`.

Но при билде выскакивают следующие ошибки, которые я не знаю, как исправить:

```
> ||=== Build: Debug in server (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0xce)||undefined reference to
> `ass_set_frame_size'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0xf3)||undefined reference to
> `ass_set_shaper'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x129)||undefined reference to
> `ass_set_aspect_ratio'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x1d2)||undefined reference to
> `ass_render_frame'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `uninit':| (.text.unlikely+0x16)||undefined reference to
> `ass_free_track'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `uninit':| (.text.unlikely+0x25)||undefined reference to
> `ass_renderer_done'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init':| (.text.unlikely+0x75)||undefined reference to
> `ass_library_init'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init':| (.text.unlikely+0xaf)||undefined reference to
> `ass_set_message_cb'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init':| (.text.unlikely+0xc1)||undefined reference to
> `ass_set_fonts_dir'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init':| (.text.unlikely+0xcc)||undefined reference to
> `ass_renderer_init'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init_ass':| (.text.unlikely+0x144)||undefined reference to
> `ass_set_fonts'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init_ass':| (.text.unlikely+0x15e)||undefined reference to
> `ass_read_file'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init_subtitles':| (.text.unlikely+0x1e9)||undefined
> reference to `ass_new_track'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init_subtitles':| (.text.unlikely+0x437)||undefined
> reference to `ass_add_font'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init_subtitles':| (.text.unlikely+0x474)||undefined
> reference to `ass_set_fonts'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init_subtitles':| (.text.unlikely+0x60a)||undefined
> reference to `ass_set_style_overrides'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init_subtitles':| (.text.unlikely+0x649)||undefined
> reference to `ass_process_codec_private'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `init_subtitles':| (.text.unlikely+0x7e6)||undefined
> reference to `ass_process_chunk'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_subtitles.o)||In
> function `uninit':| (.text.unlikely+0x39)||undefined reference to
> `ass_library_done'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x82)||undefined reference to
> `vsFrameInfoInit'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0xf1)||undefined reference to
> `vsMotionDetectInit'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0xf7)||undefined reference to
> `VS_OK'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x10d)||undefined reference to
> `vsMotionDetectGetConfig'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x247)||undefined reference to
> `vsPrepareFile'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x24f)||undefined reference to
> `VS_OK'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x3e4)||undefined reference to
> `vsMotionDetection'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x3ea)||undefined reference to
> `VS_OK'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x44a)||undefined reference to
> `vsWriteToFile'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x450)||undefined reference to
> `VS_OK'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x48c)||undefined reference to
> `vs_vector_del'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabdetect.o)||In
> function `uninit':| (.text.unlikely+0x35)||undefined reference to
> `vsMotionDetectionCleanup'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x7a)||undefined reference to
> `vsFrameInfoInit'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0xaf)||undefined reference to
> `vsFrameInfoInit'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x15e)||undefined reference to
> `vsTransformDataInit'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x168)||undefined reference to
> `VS_OK'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x17a)||undefined reference to
> `vsTransformGetConfig'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x361)||undefined reference to
> `getInterpolationTypeName'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x3b1)||undefined reference to
> `vsReadLocalMotionsFile'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x3bb)||undefined reference to
> `VS_OK'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x3db)||undefined reference to
> `vsReadOldTransforms'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x3fb)||undefined reference to
> `vsPreprocessTransforms'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x401)||undefined reference to
> `VS_OK'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x458)||undefined reference to
> `vsLocalmotions2Transforms'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `config_input':| (.text+0x45e)||undefined reference to
> `VS_OK'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x662)||undefined reference to
> `vsTransformGetSrcFrameInfo'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x687)||undefined reference to
> `vsTransformGetSrcFrameInfo'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x6b5)||undefined reference to
> `vsTransformGetDestFrameInfo'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x6e7)||undefined reference to
> `vsTransformPrepare'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x702)||undefined reference to
> `vsGetNextTransform'|
> ../../../../../opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_vidstabtransform.o)||In
> function `filter_frame':| (.text+0x768)||undefined reference to
> `vsDoTransform'| ||More errors follow but not being shown.| ||Edit the
> max errors limit in compiler options...| ||=== Build failed: 50
> error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 5 second(s)) ===|
```

**PS** Code Blocks не критичен. Если у Вас есть работающие варианты для других IDE - напишите их в ответ(IDE и как для него собрать и подключить ffmpeg)

**UPDATE1:**
На машине установлены: `libass-dev0.13`, `libass4`, `libass5`, `libassa3.5-5`, `libassa3.5-5-dev`, `libassuan0`. Добавил ключ в начало списока ключей выше: `-lass`. Ничего не изменилось. Также указал их в `Build options-> Search directories -> Linker`

**UPDATE2:** переустановил ffmpeg [как тут](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu), ошибки такие же

Comment: Видимо нужную либу не может найти. Можете попробовать подрубить все ffmpeg либы, наверное в одной из них она есть.

Comment: Проверьте разрядность подключаемых библиотек и собираемого приложения.

Comment: Возможно порядок подключения важен. Хотя я не уверен

Comment: *туда (в **/opt**) установился ffmpeg* — я бы не рекомендовал пользоваться столь **криво** собранными пакетами.

Comment: @Dmitry А libass у вас подключена?

Comment: @@alexander а как Вы предлагаете?

Comment: @Dmitry Ну например [тут](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libass) или [тут](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libass-dev). Можно вот это ещё почитать: [How to enable libass on Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116036/how-to-enable-libass-on-linux)

Comment: @Embedder libass установлена на машине, на которой делается проект. Установлены различные версии(libass-dev0.13, libass4, libass5, libassa3.5-5). Попытался добавить ключ -lass в начало списка ключей - эффект тот же. ffmpeg говорит, что он собран с libass enabled

Comment: @Dmitry ну тогда могу порекомендовать только одно - [CompilationGuide/Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). Тут вот ещё вот в чем дело: Code::Blocks делает автогенерацию make-файлов, и чего он там нагенерил неизвестно. У FFmpeg много различных опций сборки, поэтому я бы собрал все "штатным" способом, через командную строку.